# How to use blocks to handle errors returned by NS methods

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsstring, objective-c-blocks

I created a file using the following code:

```
    NSMutableString *tabString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];  //  it will automatically expand

//  write column headings  <----- TODO

//  now write out the data to be exported
for(int i = 0; i < booksArray.count; i++)  {
    [tabString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\t,%@\t,%@\t\n",
                             [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] author],
                             [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] binding],
                             [[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] bookDescription]]];
}

if (![self checkForDataFile: @"BnN.tab"])  //  does the file exist?
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:documentsPath contents: nil attributes:nil];  //  create it if not

NSFileHandle *handle;
handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsPath, @"BnN.tab"]];  //  <---------- userID?
[handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];   //  tell handle where's the file fo write
[handle writeData:[tabString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  //position handle cursor to the end of file  (why??)
```

This is the code I am using to read back the file (for debugging purposes):

```
    //  now read it back
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsPath, @"BnN.tab"]
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error: ^{ NSLog(@"error: %@", (NSError **)error);
                                                 }];
```

I am getting 2 build errors on this last statement that says:

> Sending 'void (^)(void)' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSError *__autoreleasing *'

and

> Use of undeclared identifier 'error'

This is the first time I am using a block to handle method returned errors;  I was unable to find any docs in SO or Google showing how to do this.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you can pass a block to a parameter with a type of `NSError **`?

Comment: Uhh... I saw it in an example...wrong, huh?   It's the *block* I'm having problems with...  SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is expecting an `NSError**` parameter, not a block. The way you should be calling it is something like:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsPath, @"BnN.tab"]
                                              encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error: &error];
if (content == nil) {
    NSLog("error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: This is *not* the correct way to check for an error condition. As documented in Apple's "Error Handling Programming Guide", you should always check the *return value*, in this case `if (content == nil)`, and evaluate the error variable only if the return value indicates an error.

Comment: @MartinR good point, fixed. I guess I've been spending too much time in the node.js world lately and got a little ahead of myself :)

Comment: RATS!  As mentioned in my comment to rmaddy's comment, I saw blocks used as error handlers in my search of Google... so my next question is:  how can I tell if I can use a block or not?

Comment: @spokane-dude You can use a block if the parameter takes a block.